Can saxophones be in the clef as their name?
For example, can alto sax be in alto clef, tenor sax in tenor clef, etc.

It might be the one sure-fire way to get them to play quietly. :)

Only when an Eb  sax is covering another instrument's part written in  C in Bass clef. Instant transposition!   :-)   {as linac wrote in his answer below}

It's certainly possible, but it is not done by convention, and the large majority of saxophone players will have significant difficulty reading those clefs.  Many will likely refuse.
The convention that the tenor saxophone transposes by a major ninth might make nontransposing tenor clef easier to read than the other possibilities (e.g. alto in alto clef, soprano in soprano clef, etc.), but all the accidentals will be off, so it will still be a bit confusing.

If we review perusal scores for significant recent works that include saxophone parts, such as "Halcyon Hearts" by Katahj Copley and "Vesuvius" by Frank Tichelli, we will consistently see that all saxophones are written in treble clef.
The reason for this is that the four most common members of the sax family (soprano, alto, tenor, baritone), all use essentially the same fingering but different transpositions. This means that when a sax player has learned the fingering for the written notes on one type of sax, they can transfer that knowledge to another type of sax without having to learn to read for a different fingering.
If that doesn't already make sense to you, then I'm afraid a more detailed and clear explanation would be much longer. Trust that the professional composers working today, such as Copley and Tichelli (and I'm confident any others you could find), are engraving sax parts correctly so that sax players can effectively read and play the parts. If you want your parts read and played well, you should do likewise.
Always write sax parts in treble clef

As the other answers have correctly stated, it just isn't conventional and therefore most (non-professional) saxophone players will not be able to read in a different clef. But it would certainly be possible.
Skilled players that are used to switching between different saxophones are often able to play an alto part (E♭) on tenor (B♭) or vice versa. For those, it would probably be easy to also learn to read alto or tenor clefs.
The one exception that I have seen quite often is for baritone saxophone players to read bass clef in C. There are two reasons:

Tuba, bassoon and a few other instruments in that range are written that way. Occasionally baritone sax has to take over that part.
It literally lines up. Key signature and accidentals do not, but the notes happen to be on the "same lines" when looking at treble in E♭ vs. bass in C.


There are many conventions in music and life in general which could be different or better.  However, frequently the cost of the change outweighs the benefit or just inertia is too high.  Also, even if you see a different convention as better, it is likely that someone else will disagree.
A non-musical example is which side of the road to drive on.  It would be nice if we all agreed but the cost and disruption of changing is just too great.
Back to saxophones.  There is an advantage to the current system.  I own a tenor saxophone and I have also played alto and baritone.  It is convenient that when I see a written note, e.g. G in the treble clef, I use the same fingering on all the instruments.  I have not played a soprano saxophone but I expect that I could easily.
However, it could be different.  Recorders come in a family similar to the saxophones but they do not use this system.  So, if I play an unfamiliar recorder, I need to ask or experiment to figure out which fingerings to use for which notes.
The benefit to not using the transposing notation is probably mostly for non-players e.g. composers and conductors.  This benefit is probably reducing due to the prevalence of software to write and edit scores.  You could compose for a saxophone ensemble by writing in concert pitch using whichever clefs you liked yet easily print out the parts transposed as the players are familiar with.
I think that clefs other than treble and bass are less popular than they used to be.  Their use is mostly in a few traditional cases such as the viola.
You could ask your question of vocal parts.  Alto and tenor vocal parts are rarely written in those clefs; at least not today.
Finally, the names soprano, alto, tenor, bass etc are used for some families of instruments to indicate their relative pitch but that does not necessarily mean that their range suits the clef of the same name.  For example, the bass recorder would use little of the bass clef if it was not written an octave lower than it sounds.

Nice question! However, most, if not all players, are so used to playing using dots that are compensated to work for B♭ and/or E♭, that they would baulk at the thought of anything else. I know I would!
EDIT: of course they can. Trouble is, there would be few, if any, players who would be happy playing in a different clef from the treble that they're used to using. There would be no point, though, as the treble clef that is used will actually comfortably cover all the notes needed to be written (and played), so there would be little or no point in changing the clef to suit the name of the instrument.

Does this answer the question? It doesn't seem to mention clefs, only transposition

@ToddWilcox - edited it accordingly. Happier now?

Yes, much better
